# for loop prints 'undefined' when trying to decrement

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm having trouble understanding why this prints my request:

`for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  console.log(i);
 }`

And why this code will not:

`for (var i = 15; i < 0; i--) {
  console.log(i);
 }`

I need to create a for loop that prints all numbers from 15 to 0.

Comment: `i < 0`   ->  `i >= 0`      The second part of a for loop is the while condition, so your saying while i is less than 0, well it never is as your starting at 15 so then will immediately exit the loop.

Comment: `i < 0` condition is never true, so your loop does not perform any iterations. You may want to use `i >= 0` instead. But please-please-please, ensure you understand **why** you need that instead.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I went through that process, but I guess I didn't... :(

Comment: Or try to use `for(i=0; i<=15;i++) console.log(15-i);`

Answer (score 1):

the issue in you for loop is that initial value of i is 15 , you are giving a condition of 15 < 0 , then on the next iteration its reducing value to 15 -1 which is 14 and checking 14 < 0. So that's why its printing undefined

why undefined is printing since you have declared the i.

```
var a;
console.log(a) // undefined
```

```js
 
 //Instead of 
for (var i = 15; i < 0; i--) {
  console.log(i);
 }

 // working one
 for (var i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(i);
 }
```

Comment: `undefined` is output there because statements don't return values. If you run your "working" solution it would also output `undefined` as the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(i);
 }
```

For decrements the values use '>' sign instead of '<'. Hope it will help you.

Comment: "For decrements the values use '>' sign instead of '<'." --- this is the worst advice one may give to a beginner.